# User Control Click - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a custom user control on my windows forms. This control has a few labels on it.

I will be dynamically displaying an array of these controls on my form which will contain different bits of data.

What I am trying to do is know which user control was selected when I click on it.

This works when I click on an empty space on the user control, however, if I click on any label on the user control it will not recognize the user control click.

Any thoughts on how I can do a full user control click, even if a label on the control is being clicked?

If this question is not clear, or you need more info, please leave a comment.

I am doing this in c#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User control's click event won't fire when another control is clicked on the user control. You need to manually bind each element's click event. You can do this with a simple loop on the user control's codebehind:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    // I am assuming MyUserControl_Click handles the click event of the user control.
    control.Click += MyUserControl_Click;
}
```

After this piece of code workd, MyUserControl_Click will fire when any control on the user control is clicked.

Comment: awesome! this totally helped. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you!!! Please note that you should include a recursive add/remove for Controls that are inside Controls (For example Controls inside a Panel)

Comment: Also you shouldn't forget to check the object types in your event-method: `public void MyUserControl_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 { if(sender.GetType() is Label) {...} } `. Otherwise you could easily run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        c.Click += new EventHandler(SameAsForm_Click);
    }
```

Keep in mind that this won't add labels' clickevents in groupboxes, panels etc to the "SameAsForm_Click"-EventHandler.