# User control click event not working when clicking on text inside control?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, onclick, mouse

I have a user control called `GameButton` that has a label inside it. When I add the user control to my form, and add a click event to it, its triggered when you click on the background of the custom button, but not the text in the label? How would I fix this without adding a bunch of click events inside the user controls code?

edit: UI framework: winforms

Comment: UI framework (Winforms, WPF, Webforms, MVC)?

Comment: Also please avoid including tags that have little to nothing to do with your question (e.g. visual-studio).

Comment: By design, the Label control gets the click.  You could override OnPaint() instead of using a label as one workaround.

Comment: no the label doesnt respond to the event, but the background does...

Comment: Why are you opposed to adding a single event handler with all of the references to it necessary? You could possibly even use reflection to assign the event handler.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I am understanding you properly, your GameButton usercontrol will fire the event when clicked on, but not when the label is clicked on -- and you want both.  This is because the label (a control) is on top of the background.  Therefore, you need to register your label with the click event as well.  This can be done manually in the designer or programmatically for each control on the page.

If you want to do EVERY control in the UserControl, put this into the UserControl's OnLoad event and you can use the same click event for every control:

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls)
    c.Click += new EventHandler(yourEvent_handler_click);

public void yourEvent_handler_click (object sender, EventArgs e){
    //whatever you want your event handler to do
}
```

EDIT: The best way is to create the click event handler property in the user control.  This way, every time you add/remove a click event to your user control, it adds/removes it to all the controls within the user control automatically.

```
public new event EventHandler Click {
        add {
            base.Click += value;
            foreach (Control control in Controls) {
                control.Click += value;
            }
        }
        remove {
            base.Click -= value;
            foreach (Control control in Controls) {
                control.Click -= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is as per another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820490/click-event-for-net-windows-forms-user-control):

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wanted to be able to add click events to my custom buttons the way you do with regular buttons in the designer, but they don't affect the label

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @EfeOzturkoglu.  You want your usercontrol to be as if it were a regular button where you can click on it anywhere with one event handler?

Comment: yeah, like i dont want to have to add a handler to the control AND the label inside it each time, just add it once whenever i create a new instance of the button

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new method and assign all the controls to it

```
private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.OnClick(e);
}
```

This will raise main control(or usercontrol) event.

Comment: Thank you sir!! this is a clever solution

Answer (score 1):

Set the "enable" property of your labels "False, then mouse events will work in user control.

Comment: Wrong solution as this will also gray out controls.

Comment: its works to me! i set enable false for all child controls in my user control!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the events in the controls of the User Control call the event of the User Control like that:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    c.Click += (sender, e) => { this.OnClick(e); };
    c.MouseUp += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseUp(e); };
    c.MouseDown += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseDown(e); };
    c.MouseMove+= (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseMove(e); };
}
```

Just put it in the constructor. This way when an event is added to the User Control using polymorphism it will work

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here This control has 4 child control like 3 label and 1 picturebox.
so add `this.onClick(e)` in **c#** or `Me.onClick(e)` in **vb.net** on there on click event
like this

```
Private Sub rate_lab_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rate_lab.Click
    Me.OnClick(e)
End Sub
```

[image]
So wherever click inside  user control the click event act as single event