# Click handler does not fire when user control cast to Control

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a WinForms user control when I have hidden Control.Click using

```
public new event EventHandler Click
{
    add
    {
        base.Click += value;
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            control.Click += value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677062/user-control-click-event-not-working-when-clicking-on-text-inside-control)).  This works well and all is fine and dandy, *until* I cast it to a generic `Control` (for example when passing a reference to something that knows nothing about the specific user control type).

In this case, when adding a click handler it is bound to the base Control_Click, completely bypassing the above method that was supposed to hide the base method.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Such are the hazards of using the *new* keyword to suppress that strongly-worded compiler warning.  Just don't do this, there is no point in micro-optimizing code that runs at human-time.  Iterate the controls in the constructor and subscribe their Click events, have the event handler call OnClick().

Comment: Thank you Hans.  Sometimes, after using the _generic/lazy_ way it is easy to miss the blindingly obvious.  At least for me.